# In ICU, is it possible to use custom plural rules instead of CLDR rules

Tags: php, internationalization, icu, plural, cldr

So I want to use a different plural rule than what is in the [CLDR](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html). I'm using ICU through PHP [intl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php), and say I have something like this:

```
$msg = new MessageFormatter('ar',
                '{0,plural,  zero {zero-ar}' .
                'one {one-ar}' .
                'two {two-ar}' .
                'few {{0,number} few-ar}' .
                'many {{0,number} many-ar}' .
                'other{{0,number} other-ar} }.');
```

I'm not happy with the built in plural rule for one of the categories and would like to change it, is that possible? And no it's not just fixed intervals, so can't use choices.

Comment: may I ask what you're not happy with, specifically? (Just to understand) http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#ar

Comment: V. brief: In Arabic, each noun has singular, dual, plural forms, eg tree: shajara=tree-1 shajaratan=tree-2 ashjar=trees. For the case X100+1,+2, eg (102 trees) the traditional style is to use singular or dual forms rather than count subject: so (100 and tree-1, 100 and tree-2) instead of (102 tree-x-form). Now the 2nd style is acceptable and is used to avoid having special cases and usability issues with 1st style. However, it's fringe and correct tree-x-form is debatable - the CLDR has got it wrong on this case - there is a discussion here (http://wiki.arabeyes.org/Plural_Forms) (link down?).

Comment: In every comment I run out of space to thank you:)- really thanks fro your helpful answers.

Comment: glad to help. but,  http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#ar looks the same as the "6 forms" given on the arabeyes page. The discussion part of arabeyes only seems to agree with CLDR. In anyways, please file a bug against CLDR: http://cldr.unicode.org

Comment: Sorry the links weren't working when I posted. The proper link is here: http://wiki.arabeyes.org/%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A1_%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%84_%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%BA_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%AF. Unfortunately the page is Arabic only - there is a link to an English version at the top - but the English version doesn't discuss the issue. Basically they leave the matter open for further submissions. I'll pursue the matter later - many thanks.

Comment: glad to help. The page says it was updated in 2008… I attempted to read it given machine translation and trying to sound out the Arabic words compared to Maltese (which I'm a little more familiar with). Wasn't totally clear to me. Please also see http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/ticket/1671 where there was some discussion. It would be important to cite some specific reference sources such as a dictionary or grammar at this point, or some written established documents as that bug claimed extensive review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to create a PluralRules object using `PluralRules.createRules()` and then create your own `PluralFormat` using those rules and a pattern.

Comment: I don't see this exposed in the PHP API, so I'll have to use workarounds in my code.

Comment: You could checkout ICU from the subversion tag and then edit icu/source/data/misc/plurals.txt - perhaps you could come back here with what you actually changed?